# Atmel Studio 6 Simulator Not Showing Up

Tags: atmel, debugging, atmel-studio

I was looking to run the simulator for an AVR controller, but when I went to set my debugging tools as outlined in this video- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QlDSNeuAdY

I do not have anything show up under the drop down both on my PC and Mac running windows in Parallels.

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Are there any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure atfw.exe runs without problems (found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.2\atbackend). I found atfw.exe was missing wdapi1010.dll.

Copy wdapi1010.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel USB Drivers\Jungo\usb64 to the atfw.exe directory. Now simulator and programmer are avail in Atmel Studio 6.2.

Comment: Simple1234's answer worked for me too. I had the same problem after upgrading to Studio 6.2.1548 SP2. Following these instructions restored both the simulator and my AVR Dragon.

Answer (score 1):

Not all AVR devices are supported by the simulator and in that case you'll get the empty list when you don't have a compatible programmer / debugger connected either. The following page shows simulator support for each device family:

[Atmel Studio Supported Devices](http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/atmelstudio/supported_devices.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it is an elaborate Atmel Studio bug.
Here is the description of my problem and the way I solved it:

There was a file "fuses.c" included in the project. It was created long time ago in a different version of Atmel Studio (4). I always thought that it doesn't compile to anything during debugging and is probably supposed to be used by programmer.

The Atmel Studio Bug is, that if a fuses.c file with the wrong fuse values included in the project, then the simulator glitches, stops working and disappears from the tools list! And it doesn't show up in any other project, unless you restart Atmel Studio IDE.

So, generally, removing fuses.c from the project resolved the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with an old patch.
It works for me with Windows 8.1 and Atmel Studio 6.2. My problem was the Jungo driver that was not properly installed.

http://avr-jungo-usb.software.informer.com/download/